# Assigning a color according to a floating variable

Tags: r

Let's say we have the following dataset:

```
a   b   c
s   1   10
s   2   20
ss  1   30
ss  2   40
```

We plot it like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
data <- read.table("data.stats", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
ggplot(data, aes(b, c, color=a)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line")
dev.off()
```

And this is the result:

[image]

However my actual dataset instead of strings for `a` contains floating numbers. So it might look like this:

```
a   b   c
0.1 1   10
0.1 2   20
0.5 1   30
0.5 2   40
```

If I try to run the same code however, I get a straight line as an output.

[image]

How to make R treat `a` as if the numbers are strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 > data.frame(a = c(0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5),
            b = c(1,2,1,2), c = c(10,20,30,40)
           ) %>% dplyr::mutate(a = as.character(a)) %>% ggplot(., 
           aes(b, c, color=a)) + stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line")
```

[image]